# ASP.NET MVC3 Tutorials Your First ASP.NET MVC not Create

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a newbie with respect to ASP.NET MVC 3 . I  am following the the tutorials as described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part5-cs) . The form submission fails when trying to create a new record.

Images are attached.

Submit Page : [image]
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details : [image]
Error Page : [image]

I need assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Please put the exception details (text) and the code that is throwing inline. Include what you are trying to do. Make it easy for us to answer your question, including making it clear what the question *is*.

Answer (score 1):

You are entering the date as `1/1/2011`. The error message is `An overflow occured while converting to DateTime`.

The conversion of a `string` into a `DateTime` is dependent on your system locale and how dates are written. Try to write the date in exactly the same form as shown in the system tray.

Comment: How could you make out that "An overflow occured while converting to DateTime". I looked at the entire image upside down but didn't find this anywhere ??

Comment: sorry i didn't checked those links :-P .... Anyways, it will be interesting to see if the code works for 1/1/1989 because they both are in same string format.